# Writing jest test for chained functions in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express, jestjs

I have a function i want to test with jest, the function basicly does some token verifying and takes 3 params

this is de code of the function i want to test:

```
const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
    // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
    var token = req.headers['x-access-token']

    if (!token) return res.status(403).send({ auth: false, message: 'No token provided.' })

    // verifies secret and checks expire date
    jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({ auth: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' })

        //put user inside req.user to use the user in other routes
        User.findById(decoded.id, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    message: err
                })
            } else if (!user) {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    message: 'No user found'
                })
            } else {
                req.user = user
            }
            next()
        })
    })
}
```

so i'm writing a first test, which tests if no token is given in de request, that it sends a 403 with a message. following is the test.

```
const verifyToken = require('../../config/token')

describe('veryfiy token tests', () => {
    it('Should give 403 status when no token is present', () => {
        let mockReq = {
            headers: {}
        }
        var mockRes = {
            status: code => code
            send: message => message
        }

        let nextCalled = false

        let next = () => {
            nextCalled = true
        }

        expect(verifyToken(mockReq, mockRes, next)).toBe(403)
    })
})
```

Now the test passes with an error: 
TypeError: res.status(...).send is not a function

when i removed .send() from res.status in the code, the test passes.

I have been trying to figure out how to mock both status() and send() on the res object. but have not found a solution yet.

Tnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that the result of `res.status()` does not have a function called `send()`.

Try using this:

```
  var mockRes = {
    status: code => ({
      send: message => ({code, message})
    }),
  };
```

You should be able to test with:

```
  var result = verifyToken(mockReq, mockRes, next);
  expect(result.code).toBeDefined();
  expect(result.code).toBe(403);
```

PS: Haven't tested the code :)

Comment: This worked! i did not know i had to nest the functions. tnx for the example!

Answer (score 0):

you can make chained mock class and test, wether functions are executed or not.

here is an example.

```
  class MockResponse {
    constructor() {
    this.res = {};
     }
     status = jest
     .fn()
     .mockReturnThis()
     .mockImplementationOnce((code) => {
       this.res.code = code;
      return this;
     });
    send = jest
    .fn()
    .mockReturnThis()
    .mockImplementationOnce((message) => {
      this.res.message = message;
      return this;
    });
    }
```

and now use this mock class to test. and check given function has executed with given result or not.
example like

```
  it("should not call next function, and return 401, if token has not been found", async () => {
      let res = new MockResponse(); // here i initialised instance of class
      let  next = jest.fn();
      let req = {cookies:""} // header or cookies where you are receiving token here in my case empty.
       await authentication(req, res, next); // here i used my mock res class
      expect(next).not.toHaveBeenCalled(); // you must check that next will not be called. 
      expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(401);//you can check result of status
      expect(res.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith("not authenticated");// send() message in your function
    });
```